# HTC Hydra does not show the password and username obtained

Tags: hydra

I am doing a practice with Hydra in Kali Linux 2020. The problem i have is that when finish the process and obtain a correct password, it does not show me the password obtained, what it does show is the name of my text files with users and passwords.

```
hydra -l /home/elunadanilo/Desktop/username.txt -p /home/elunadanilo/Desktop/password.txt 127.0.0.1 http-form-post "/api/user/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&login=^Login^: Password incorrecto" -V
```

I read the documentation at:

https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra

I made an attempt changing in the command -l for -L and -p for -P also -L for -l and -p for -P and if it shows me the obtained keys but not what is the correct key.

[image: KaliL]

Please help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: I do not understand. The output clearly shows the username/password combinations that it found... It ***thinks*** all 41 credentials worked. It is very clearly saying that. Your question really is, "why does it think all 41 are correct?" And that's because your test for a failed password is faulty ...

Comment: @schroeder they're clearly false positives. Has happened to me too in the past. Most probably the HTTP-form syntax specified is not correct. Intercept a request with burp suite, analyze it (eventually make a try with burp suite itself to log in - there is a feature to do that) and retry to rebuild the correct request in hydra.

Comment: @Virgula yes, I know they are false-positives. But the question asked is wrong. It IS showing what it thinks it obtained.